# Collision detection not working as intended (Arrays, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection, collision

Ill start off by saying im not the best at explaining.

I have attached 2 images to help explain with my problem.

The problem is that the 'player' is colliding with the 'square 2' X position, when it is clearly not in range of the Y position. The green line shows where the player is colliding and stopping, (stopping as in if you hit a wall, you would stop). In image 2, below the black line, is the expected outcome, how do I achieve this? (Scroll for code)

[image]

[image]

Just in case you need to know, the enemy/player is 50x50px, the rectangle is 70x150px

My Code (JS):

```
    blockX.forEach(blockX => { // left and right collision
    blockY.forEach(blockY => {
        if (enemy.y + enemy.h >= blockY && enemy.y <= blockY + rect.h) {
                if (enemy.x + enemy.w >= blockX) {
                    if (enemy.x <= blockX + enemy.w) {
                        enemy.x = blockX - enemy.w
                    }
                }
                if (enemy.x <= blockX + rect.w + 13) {
                    if (enemy.x + enemy.w >= blockX) {
                        enemy.x = blockX + rect.w + 13
                    }
                } 
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: I assume the rectangle `x` and `y` coordinates are the coordinates of the top left corner of the rectangle?

Comment: @Mushroomator yes correct.

Comment: Remove the last two else statements, because they are overwriting whatever comes from the first if statement.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can simplify the code by resetting `collision.cr` at the beginning of the function, and then all you have to do is set it to `true` once if met condition, no need for any `else`

Second, you should have a single condition, that checks both `x` and `y` coordinates, not two separates (which by the way, in your code the second condition WILL overwrite previous condition's result, because of the `else`)

```js
const elPlayer = document.getElementById("player");
const enemies = [
  {
    x: 100,
    y: 34,
    w: 100,
    h: 150
  },
  {
    x: 300,
    y: 34,
    w: 100,
    h: 150
  },
  {
    x: 140,
    y: 54,
    w: 100,
    h: 50
  }
];


window.addEventListener("mousemove", e =>
{
  const player = {
    x: e.x,
    y: e.y,
    w: 20,
    h: 20
  }

//colistion detection
  for(let i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++)
  {
    const enemy = enemies[i];
    const collide = (enemy.x < player.x + player.w &&
                    enemy.x + enemy.w > player.x &&
                    enemy.y < player.y + player.h &&
                    enemy.y + enemy.h > player.y)

    elPlayer.classList.toggle("collide", collide);
    if (collide)
      break;
  }

  elPlayer.style.top = player.y + "px";
  elPlayer.style.left = player.x + "px";
});


[...document.querySelectorAll(".enemy")].forEach((enemy, i) =>
{
  enemy.style.left = enemies[i].x + "px";
  enemy.style.top = enemies[i].y + "px";
  enemy.style.width = enemies[i].w + "px";
  enemy.style.height = enemies[i].h + "px";
});
```

```css
.enemy
{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#player
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


#player.collide
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="enemy"></div>
<div class="enemy"></div>
<div class="enemy"></div>

<div id="player"></div>
```

Comment: how can i make that collision, but with arrays?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, the `for` is a loop through array of `enemies`...

Comment: an array - let myArray = [ ],
       myArray.push(100)

Comment: Well, I know what an array is, what I don't know is what exactly you don't understand...the example is using arrays...

Comment: ok so, the reason i am using this type of array, is because I don't want to have to type every individual thing into 'your' array. ill briefly explain the feature that I'm making in my game: In short, you left click and it will spawn a rectangle, then it will push the X coordinate to blockX, and then push the Y coordinate to blockY. When an enemy collides with said rectangle, it will stop in its place. understand?

Comment: array is array, it doesn't matter if you "push" to it, or manually type everything. Simply adopt to the parameters are stored in the array, I have no idea the structure of your object/arrays, so can't help you with that. If you have separate arrays for x and y coordinates, perhaps you should re-evaluate how you store the data, it's better store data as array of objects, all in one array, like in the example above the `enemies` array